# Beamer and enumerate environment in article

Tags: beamer, enumerate, article

I have the following frame:

```
 \documentclass[article]{beamer}
 \usepackage{beamerarticle}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}[<+->][$(1)$]
  \item Text.
  \item Text.
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

That is, I want an ordered list with a custom counter and want to reveal it in steps (locally).  This works well, except in article mode the first brackets are used as item labels and LaTeX throws an error.  Is there a way to ignore the first brackets when compiling the file as an article?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/waBLE.png  Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: ... my guess would be that you are either missing the beamerarticle package or you load incompatible package. Without seeing some code ...

Comment: Hm.  I can produce the error with this minimal file: 

\documentclass[article]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+(1)->][$(1)$]
    \item Some text.
    \item More text.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code there.

Comment: Aha!  It's been a long time I tried to use Beamer for articles.  And I was initially using the beamerswitch package, which can do simply \document[article]{beamerswitch}

Comment: Drilling down futher into the problem, it seems that it was caused by the `paralist` package in my original file (not the minimal example).  I already knew `enumitem` is not compatible with Beamer, and it seems the same applies to `paralist` (adding this comment to record this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `beamerarticle` package is meant to be used with classes other than `beamer`, e.g. the `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}[<+->][$(1)$]
  \item Text.
  \item Text.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]